# Export-Csv help in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Below is the latter part of a script that I have adopted to perform a remote inventory of hosts on my network. I am struggling with the Export-Csv at the end of the script. The only way I can get .csv file is to substitute the "-Append" for "-Force" As expected, only the last host in the specified file in the foreach loop is written to the file (because the loop overwrites each entry without the "-Append" so I am left with only the last host's information in the exported CSV file). With the -Append, the CSV file is not even created; I have also tried to create the CSV file prior to running the script, however, nothing is written to the file. What am I doing wrong?

```
  foreach ($Network in $Networks) {
$IPAddress  = $Network.IpAddress[0]
$MACAddress  = $Network.MACAddress
$systemBios = $Bios.serialnumber
$OutputObj  = New-Object -Type PSObject
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $Computer.ToUpper()
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Manufacturer -Value $Hardware.Manufacturer
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Model -Value $Hardware.Model
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CPU_Info -Value $cpu.Name
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SystemType -Value $Hardware.SystemType
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name BuildVersion -Value $SysBuild.BuildVersion
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name OS -Value $OS.Caption
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SPVersion -Value $OS.csdversion
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SerialNumber -Value $systemBios
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IPAddress -Value $IPAddress
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MACAddress -Value $MACAddress
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UserName -Value $username.Name
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Last-Login -Value $username.LastWriteTime
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name C:_GBfreeSpace -Value $driveSpace.GBfreespace
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Total_Physical_Memory -Value $totalMemory
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Last_Reboot -Value $lastboot
$OutputObj | Export-Csv -Append -Path "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Scripts\pcInventory.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Do you get any exception? What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the response. No exception. I am running PSVersion 2.0

Comment: The Append parameter for Export-Csv was only introduced in PowerShell 3.0

Comment: I did not know that. I suppose that is why it worked at home and not at work. Does that suggest it is impossible to complete the objective outlined in the script? I am trying to collect an inventory of all of the PCs in my OU, but I run into a problem every time I have more than one system to run against.

Comment: No, it's definitely not impossible. I'll add a quick answer .

Answer (score 0):

(not tested) one option would be to put the export outside your loop like this

```
$results = foreach ($Network in $Networks) {
    $IPAddress = $Network.IpAddress[0]
    $MACAddress = $Network.MACAddress
    $systemBios = $Bios.serialnumber

    [pscustomobject]@{
        ComputerName = $Computer.ToUpper()
        Manufacturer = $Hardware.Manufacturer
        Model = $Hardware.Model
        CPU_Info = $cpu.Name
        SystemType = $Hardware.SystemType
        BuildVersion = $SysBuild.BuildVersion
        OS = $OS.Caption
        SPVersion = $OS.csdversion
        SerialNumber = $systemBios
        IPAddress = $IPAddress
        MACAddress = $MACAddress
        UserName = $username.Name
        Last_Login = $username.LastWriteTime
        C_GBfreeSpace = $driveSpace.GBfreespace
        Total_Physical_Memory = $totalMemory
        Last_Reboot = $lastboot
    }
}

$results | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Scripts\pcInventory.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I assigned the foreach loop to a variable and placed the export-csv outside of the loop as recommended, however, this leaves me with an empty CSV.

Comment: @adequ `[pscustomobject]@{ ... }` is also v3 feature. You need to use `New-Object PSObject -Property @{ ... }` in v2 instead or use your `Add-Member` code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this outside the loop. I haven't tested it for your example.

```
$rows | ConvertTo-Csv | Add-Content 'C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Scripts\pcInventory.csv'
```

Add this before the loop starts:

```
$rows = @()
```

And add this just before the end of the loop:

```
$rows += $OutputObj
```

Here's an example using a dummy object:

```
$Networks = @("Network1", "Network2") 
$rows = @()

foreach ($Network in $Networks) {

    $OutputObj  = New-Object -Type PSObject
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $Network
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Manufacturer -Value $Network
    $rows += $OutputObj

}

$outFile  =  'C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Scripts\pcInventory.csv'

# Need the following to avoid adding header row each time.
if (test-path $outFile){
    $ExistingRowCount = (Import-Csv "$outFile" | measure-Object).Count
    if ($ExistingRowCount -gt 0){
        $rowToStartAppending = 1
    }else{
        $rowToStartAppending = 0
    }
}else{
    $rowToStartAppending = 0
}

$csvContent = $rows | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
$csvContent[$rowToStartAppending..$csvContent.count] | Add-Content $outFile
```

Comment: I created the array. The script runs just fine and the csv file is populated. However, it is still overwriting all but the last object in the loop.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, exactly. I'm editing my answer to include a more complete example. If it doesn't answer your question, you should add more code - see "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

This is one script i have other properties of what you need

```
$serverList = "c:\COMPUTERS.TXT"
$outputCSV = "D:\RFV.csv"


$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
#$dir = Split-Path $scriptpath
pushd $dir

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$sysCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($null)

foreach ($server in (Get-Content $serverList))
{
    "Collecting information from $server"
    $totCores=0

    try
    {
        [wmi]$sysInfo = get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem -Namespace "root\CIMV2" -ComputerName $server -ErrorAction Stop
        [wmi]$bios = Get-WmiObject Win32_BIOS -Namespace "root\CIMV2" -computername $server
        [wmi]$os = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -Namespace "root\CIMV2" -Computername $server
        [array]$disks = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Namespace "root\CIMV2" -Filter DriveType=3 -Computername $server
        [array]$disks = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Namespace "root\CIMV2" -Computername $server
        [array]$procs = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor -Namespace "root\CIMV2" -Computername $server
        [array]$mem = Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory -Namespace "root\CIMV2" -ComputerName $server
        [array]$nic = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Namespace "root\CIMV2" -ComputerName $server | where{$_.IPEnabled -eq "True"}

        $si = @{
            Server          = [string]$server
            Manufacturer    = [string]$sysInfo.Manufacturer
            Model           = [string]$sysInfo.Model
            TotMem          = "$([string]([System.Math]::Round($sysInfo.TotalPhysicalMemory/1gb,2))) GB"
            BiosDesc        = [string]$bios.Description
            BiosVer         = [string]$bios.SMBIOSBIOSVersion+"."+$bios.SMBIOSMajorVersion+"."+$bios.SMBIOSMinorVersion
            BiosSerial      = [string]$bios.SerialNumber
            OSName          = [string]$os.Name.Substring(0,$os.Name.IndexOf("|") -1)
            ServicePack = (“SP {0}” -f [string]$os.ServicePackMajorVersion)
            Arch            = [string]$os.OSArchitecture
            Processors      = [string]@($procs).count
            Cores           = [string]$procs[0].NumberOfCores

        }

        $disks | foreach-object {$si."Drive$($_.Name -replace ':', '')"="$([string]([System.Math]::Round($_.Size/1gb,2))) GB"}



    }
    catch [Exception]
    {
        "Error communicating with $server, skipping to next"
        $si = @{
            Server          = [string]$server
            ErrorMessage    = [string]$_.Exception.Message
            ErrorItem       = [string]$_.Exception.ItemName
        }
        Continue
    }
    finally
    {
       [void]$sysCollection.Add((New-Object PSObject -Property $si))   
    }
}

$sysCollection `
    | select-object Server,TotMem,OSName,Arch,ServicePack,Processors,Cores,Manufacturer,Model,BiosDesc,BiosVer,BiosSerial,DriveA,DriveB,DriveC,DriveD,DriveE,DriveF,DriveG,DriveH,DriveI,DriveJ,DriveK,DriveL,DriveM,DriveN,DriveO,DriveP,DriveQ,DriveR,DriveS,DriveT,DriveU,DriveV,DriveW,DriveX,DriveY,DriveZ,ErrorMessage,ErrorItem `
    | sort -Property Server `
    | Export-CSV -path $outputCSV -NoTypeInformation  
    Write-Host "inventory completed check $outputCSV" -backgroundcolor "green"
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code. I can definitely work on modifying this to retrieve all of the information I need. I was really hoping to find out why what I have is not working. I either get nothing in the csv or I get the last object in the loop. Thanks again.

Comment: I dont see you have added  Get-WmiObject to pull information from WMI, the best thing you can do is remove properties of what you don't need and add what all you want.

It works flawless for me I added all info of what i need you can modify for urs

Comment: Thanks again. I was able to remove everything I did not need and I figured out how to add username, last boot time, IPv4, and MAC. Hopefully I can give back to the community with what I learned!